# infinite-scroll method not triggering

Tags: angularjs, nginfinitescroll

I'm using ngInfiniteScroll in my project to load large data into the UI.

Here is my HTML,

```
<div infinite-scroll='nextPage()'>
    <div ng-repeat="app in applications">{{app.name}}</div>
</div>
```

In my controller,

```
$scope.nextPage = function(){
    console.log("nextPage");
    $scope.page++;
    .....
}
```

`nextPage()` method is called only once. It's not triggering after the first time.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this example

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='DemoController'>
  <div infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2'>
    <img ng-repeat='image in images' ng-src='http://placehold.it/225x250&text={{image}}'>
  </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);
myApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.images = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    var last = $scope.images[$scope.images.length - 1];
    for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
      $scope.images.push(last + i);
    }
  };
});
</script>
```

Comment: I already did...even in this example `loadMore()` function is called only once in my project